# cat, file says file not found, but nano reads it; why the difference?

Tags: linux, permissions

I tried to read the content of file with `cat`, and got:

```
bandit21@melinda:/etc/cron.d$ cat /tmp/t706lds9S0RqQh9aMcz6ShpAoZKF7fgv
cat: /tmp/t706lds9S0RqQh9aMcz6ShpAoZKF7fgv: No such file or directory
```

And I tried to use `file` to see the permission and got:

```
file /tmp/t706lds9S0RqQh9aMcz6ShpAoZKF7fgv
/tmp/t706lds9S0RqQh9aMcz6ShpAoZKF7fgv: ERROR: cannot open `/tmp/t706lds9S0RqQh9aMcz6ShpAoZKF7fgv' (No such file or directory)
```

However, when I tried with nano, it can be read with warning "no write permission" at bottom. There is content inside of the file when I open it with nano. So it is not a new file made by nano command.

Why am I seeing such different behavior?

Comment: What command are you using for opening the file with nano?

Comment: Just `nano {FILE_NAME}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `cat` and `file` tell you this file doesn't exist, which is its current state.

However, `nano` is not checking file existence (as it's an editor which would allow you to create that file), but rather warn you that you probably don't have write permissions in that folder (`/tmp`).

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean the file's state is not showing it to my current user? But I can read the content of  the file (here it is password) by nano which appears weird to me...

Comment: So does actually that file have some contents inside when you open the file with `nano`?

Comment: Yes and that is confusing me.

Comment: If both the `stat` and `file` commands tell you that the file doesn't exist, this is probably true. There's probably a `/tmp/t706lds9S0RqQh9aMcz6ShpAoZKF7fgv.save` file which is a "cache" file, but not actually that file. `nano` might have a "draft saving" mode which autosaves the content each short period of time. Have a look at this answer to check if it suits your situation http://askubuntu.com/questions/601985/what-are-save-files

Comment: I guess you could be right. I ran into all those above on a server. When I reboot it this morning and everything is just fine: can do  both `cat` and `file`. So I guess it must be some internal problem that I won't be able to find out anymore :(. Thanks for your efforts though.